Ubuntu Desktop wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk Green Screen
I am following the tutorial here (https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-set-up-digital-signage-on-ubuntu-frame/31068) to get some digital signage working on a Le Potato AML-S905X-CC board. When I follow the tutorial, everything seems to work but instead of a grayscale screen that goes to the wooden background with cycling images with /receiver, I instead get a solid green screen that then goes to a version with strange colors, with much lower resolution. If I restart, the boot screen ( and if I disable the daemon, the login screen and Desktop Ubuntu) all look normal and in high resolution. It's unclear to me if the problem is coming from Ubuntu-Frame or wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk.
Any suggestions? I'm not sure what logs would be helpful but am happy to provide them.
